# Возможно ли использование словосочетания?

Tags: словосочетание

Здравствуйте, уважаемые знатоки русского языка!
Возможно ли использование словосочетания "Управление повышением качества"? 
Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, возможно.Возможно же такое название диссертации"УПРАВЛЕНИЕ ПОВЫШЕНИЕМ ЭФФЕКТИВНОСТИ И КАЧЕСТВА УСЛУГ ПАССАЖИРСКОГО АВТОРАНСПОРТА В МУНИЦИПАЛЬНОМ ХОЗЯЙСТВЕ"   http://torgprice.ru/post/1000/49/54695.php 
Или такое: "Формирование модели управления процессами повышения качества..."
"Управление процессом повышения  качества труда персонала".

Идёт процесс повышения качества, им кто-то управляет. Хотя я бы всё-таки добавила слово процессом.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли!